# Convert data in annual format to financial with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I Have a dataframe structured like this:

```
______________________________________________________
|Year|JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC|
|____|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
|2016| 5 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 9 | 9 | 8 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 1 |
|____|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|___|
|2017| 3 | 4 | 3 | 5 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 2 |
```

I want to create a new row for the financial year Apr. 2016 - Apr. 2017 that takes from the 3rd column to the 11th column in row 1 and combine that with the 0th column to the 3rd column in row two.

I have tried:

```
df.loc['Apr16-Apr17'] = df.iloc[[[0], [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]] [[1], [0,1,2,3]]]
```

But I could not get that to work. What am I missing?

```
df.loc['Apr16-Apr17'] = df.iloc[[[0], [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]] <DOES SOMETHING GO HERE?> [[1], [0,1,2,3]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this for your entire DataFrame. All you need to do is `roll` your array to the left:

```
v = np.roll(df.values.ravel(), -3).astype(float)
v[-3:] = np.nan

df_annual = pd.DataFrame(
    index=df.index, columns=df.columns, data=v.reshape(-1, 12))
print(df_annual)
      JAN  FEB  MAR  APR  MAY  JUN  JUL  AUG  SEP  OCT  NOV  DEC
Year                                                            
2016  6.0  7.0  9.0  9.0  8.0  5.0  3.0  2.0  1.0  3.0  4.0  3.0
2017  5.0  8.0  8.0  7.0  6.0  4.0  3.0  3.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @coldspeed this should work a charm!  Also, how could I have the second April inclusive? i.e 13 columns (April-April (inclusive))? Then I can just drop the other row. Cheers, Skromak.

Comment: @Skromak Hmm, how will this solution generalise if you have multiple years to do this for? Will you have april inclusive for all of them (thus totalling 13 columns per row)?

Comment: I see what you're saying, I only need it for the financial year of 2016-17, but it does seem bad practice. @coldspeed